# can't import installed azure.core module

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to use the azure *get_client_from_cli_profile* to create the *ComputeClient* as I saw it on the [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-common/azure.common.client_factory?view=azure-python).

```py
import os
from getpass import getpass

from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_cli_profile

login = input("Input your login : ")
pwd = getpass("Input your password : ")
print("Logging to azure...")
command = "az login -u {} -p {}".format(login, pwd)
os.system(command)
print("Logged in !")
print("Getting ressource client...")
resource_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(ComputeManagementClient)
print("Client acquired !")
```

However, I get an error during the *get_client_from_cli_profile* saying that azure-core is not installed…

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    resource_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(ComputeManagementClient)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/common/client_factory.py", line 86, in get_client_from_cli_profile
    with_tenant=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/common/credentials.py", line 99, in get_azure_cli_credentials
    cred = _CliCredentials(profile, resource)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/common/credentials.py", line 50, in __init__
    raise ImportError("You need to install 'azure-core' to use this feature")
ImportError: You need to install 'azure-core' to use this feature
```

Here's the package in my requierments :

```
azure-cli-core
azure
azure-core
```

I verified that the package was correctly installed and if I had the right to read the folder and file and all seems good to me :

```
$ pip3 show azure-core
Name: azure-core
Version: 1.2.2
Summary: Microsoft Azure Core Library for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/core/azure-core
Author: Microsoft Corporation
Author-email: azpysdkhelp@microsoft.com
License: MIT License
Location: /home/non/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: six, requests
Required-by:
```

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/common/
total 48
drwxrwsrwx  3 root staff  4096 févr. 27 10:54 .
drwxrwsrwx 19 root staff  4096 févr. 27 10:54 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root staff 10452 févr. 27 10:54 client_factory.py
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root staff   755 févr. 27 10:54 cloud.py
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root staff  4256 févr. 27 10:54 credentials.py
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root staff   805 févr. 27 10:54 exceptions.py
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root staff  1358 févr. 27 10:54 __init__.py
drwxrwsrwx  2 root staff  4096 févr. 27 10:54 __pycache__
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root staff   328 févr. 27 10:54 _version.py
```

I tried with doing *az login* before lauching the script, it didn't change the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not need "azure-core" to use this method on a compute client, I created an issue for that:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/10041

But still, you have "azure-core" installed as you show, so that 's troubling. Could you create an issue on the issue tracker so we can have a deeper conversation?
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues

Edit: you actually hit this:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/9195

Please do no use the "azure" meta-package that doesn't work with the current "azure-cli-core", but install "azure-mgmt-compute" instead, so you should have this installed:

```
azure-mgmt-compute
azure-cli-core
azure-core  # Should not be necessary, bug 10041
```

Feel free to open an issue if that doesn't solve your problem